# Progress bar and percentages C#

Tags: c#, progress-bar

I'm making youtube mp3 downloader for desktop and i want to make progressbarr with following code:

```
    var progress = new Progress<double>(p => progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(p * 100));
        progress_label.Text = Convert.ToString(progressBar.Value) + "%";
        await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(streamInfo, browse_txtbox.Text + title + ".mp3", progress);
```

I'm using youtubeexplode library.
How to make label to refresh aswell as progress bar, beacause progress bar is working fine but i want to display percentages of progress in progress_label.

Comment: Change the single statement lambda into a code-block and add the label modification there.

Answer (score 3):

`Progress` is basically an `Action` delegate that the `DownloadMediaStreamAsync` calls periodically to update the progress. In order to do more than what you are doing, you need to modify it so that you do a code-block instead of a single call:

```
var progress = new Progress<double>(p => 
    {
        progressBar.Value = Convert.ToInt32(p * 100);
        progress_label.Text = Convert.ToString(p * 100) + "%";
    });
await client.DownloadMediaStreamAsync(streamInfo, browse_txtbox.Text + title + ".mp3", progress);
```

Now the label should also update with the progress bar. You should also be checking if you need to `Invoke` on the UI thread, I'm not sure that `Progress` will be invoked on the UI thread from `DownloadMediaStreamAsync`. I can't tell you how to do that because I'm not sure what UI framework you are using. Just be aware of the possible cross-threading issue.